# How to unhide commands in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to troubleshoot Makefile. A lot of commands are hidden using the `@` prefix. e.g.

```
all: 
    @echo "building..."
```

how can I tell make to show all the commands? I tried the `-d` option and it does not show hidden commands.

Comment: `sed -i 's/^\t@/\t/' Makefile` -- you might need literal TAB characters there rather than \t depending on your sed version.

Comment: You should rewrite your makefile.  A good technique that's easy to use is http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try running make with  V=1 or VERBOSE=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure this is what you are looking for, but here is a related technique:

Prefixing commands with `@` in a makefile recipe can be convenient, so output does not get too much cluttered, but, as you may have discovered, in some situations it can be useful to actually **see** what command is executed.

One solution is to **avoid** using the `@` character in a makefile but use instead a variable. Say, a one-letter one. Say `L`, for "log output" (but its your choice).

Then, prefix all your commands in your makefile with that variable:

```
target: prerequ
     $(L)do_this $< $@
     $(L)do_that $< $@
```

An simply define the variable, using some command-line switch:

```
ifeq "$(LOG)" ""
    LOG=no
endif

ifeq "$(LOG)" "Y"
    L=@
endif
```

Then, you can launch make from the shell like this `$make target` (no logging) or like this:

```
$ make target LOG=Y
```

And all the executed commands will show up!